# Firebase FCM Push Notifications not working on iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have developed an iOS app, in swift Xcode 11.5, and it is working fine. But when I tried to configure Firebase Cloud Messaging push Notifications, it didn't work!

I've followed the instruction on Firebase console to connect the App, and it was the Firebase account is linked correctly. and this is my AppDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, QBRTCClientDelegate {

    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcmMessageIDKey"
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
          // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

          let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
          let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
          UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
          application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        
        return true
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
      // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
      // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
      // TODO: Handle data of notification

      // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
      // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

      // Print message ID.
      if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
      }

      // Print full message.
      print(userInfo)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
      // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
      // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
      // TODO: Handle data of notification

      // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
      // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

      // Print message ID.
      if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
      }

      // Print full message.
      print(userInfo)

      completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }

}

@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

  // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              willPresent notification: UNNotification,
    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([[.alert, .sound]])
  }

  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                              withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
      print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler()
  }
}

extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
          if let error = error {
            print("Error fetching remote instance ID: \(error)")
          } else if let result = result {
            print("Remote instance ID token: \(result.token)")
          }
        }
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

        let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
        // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
        // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
        Messaging.messaging().isAutoInitEnabled = true
    }
}
```

I installed the Firebase/Core, Firebase/Analytics and Firebase/Messaging pods to the project.
I added FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to the Info.plist and set it to NO.

I've also set up the Production APNS form Apple developer account, and i think it is set correctly.

I've tested sending the Push Notifications locally from the terminal, and it is working.

But the problem is that the notifications are not being received when i do a test notification from Firebase console.

Please advise on how to solve this problem.

Comment: The code seems correct. Question: Did you correctly set the certificates for APNs (development, production) on the Firebase dashboard?

Also you have enabled on the project, in signing & capabilities -> background modes the option Remote notification?

Comment: @ingAlioth Thank you for your swift reply, Sure I have enabled the option Remote Notification, But I'll try to recheck the Production Certificate For APNS, although i followed the instruction and uploaded it previously, and there was no error message

Comment: Have you uploaded Production Certificate For APNS on the firebase settings both in development and in production? I had a similar problem in the past.

Comment: Do you mean that i upload the same Production certificate in both the development and production slots in Firebase settings? @ingAlioth

Comment: yes. If you use certificate, use just 1 Apple Push Notification service for both fields

Comment: Tried that, but unfortunately did not work either @ingAlioth